# Роутинг в Angular 6 по якорным ссылкам на другие страницы внутри проекта

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Всем привет! Проблема в следующем: внутри моего проекта на **Angular 6.1** есть ссылка `<a [routerLink]="['/pageTwo']" fragment="target">` которая должна отправлять пользователя со страницы *"/pageOne"* на страницу */pageTwo#target* **(два разных компонента)**. В результате переход происходит в **рандомное место страницы pageTwo** (не на начало, но и не на якорь таргета)
реализовывал разными способами.
Первый из них добавлял в компонент маршрута назначения (pageTwo)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fragmentSubscription = this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment) => {
        let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#' + fragment);
        if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView(!!element); }
```

я так понял такое решение подходит для большинства версий ангуляр 
и второе (актуально начиная с 6.1) 
добавить в роутер модуль данные параметры и по-моему лишнего кода не требуется

```
@NgModule( imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  scrollOffset: [0, 64] // [x, y]
})
```

ни одно из решений не помогло

п.с. по странице /pageTwo скролл работает корректно (внутри страницы), т.е. проблема только если переходить с одного роута на другой, (из одного компонента в другой)

п.п.с. может есть какой то конфликт внутри проекта?

Comment: создай пример на stackblitz или codesandbox что ли :)

Comment: проблему решил помог первый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor
всем спасибо)